# Using Nite 2 in a Qt 5 project

Tags: qt, openni, nite

I'm trying to make a Kinect skeleton tracker using Nite 2 in a Qt 5 project using Visual Studio 2012.  I included all the necessary folders in the project's properties.  Qt is working fine, but the initialization call to Nite always returns STATUS_ERROR.  I tried initializing Nite in a non-Qt program and it worked fine, so the problem seems linked to Qt.  I was able to initialize OpenNI in a Qt project.

```
// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    KinectWindow a;
    a.show();

    return app.exec();
}

// KinectWindow constructor
KinectWindow::KinectWindow(void)
    : QWidget()
{
    nite::Status status;

    status = nite::NiTE::initialize();

    if (status == nite::STATUS_ERROR)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (status == nite::STATUS_BAD_USER_ID)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (status == nite::STATUS_OUT_OF_FLOW)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The program always enters if(status == nite::STATUS_ERROR).  I tried copying the contents of the REDIST directory to the project folder, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried if it returns the aforementioned error in QtCreator, too?

Comment: I tried to add a new library for OpenNI and Nite, but Qt still didn't recognize the header files for either one.

Comment: What do you mean by "Qt still didn't recognize the header files for either one"?

Comment: It says no such file or directory.

Comment: Please paste the whole error as is. Also, in QtCreator or Visual Studio?

Comment: In Visual Studio all I get is the runtime error STATUS_ERROR. In Qt it says "Cannot open include file: 'NiTE.h': no such file or directory".  It says the same for OpenNI.h, depending on which is put first in the include directives.

Comment: You should _not_ import the external library files into your project. You should only link against the library... or if a library is header only, just include it, but definitely not import into the project. That is only necessary in rare cases.

Comment: Have you tried using a distributed version of the library rather than building it yourself? Also, do you know it entered the first error condition branch? I would suggest to print instead of debugger since it may not be valid with strong optimization level, etc. Have you tried getting more information about the error with strerror, etc?

Comment: I installed the distributed version of the library. I do know that it entered the first branch because it's returning the STATUS_ERROR status. Unfortunately, because it is a Nite Status object, I can't use strerror and Nite doesn't have a method for returning a more detailed error message like OpenNI does, so I don't really know what's causing the error.

Comment: I do not know follow? strerror is a low-level function. man strerror, you can use it in combination with the errno.

Comment: strerror(errno) returns "No Error."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Qt 5 doesn't work with NiTE at the moment, but Qt 4 does. Using Qt 4.8.5 (in Visual Studio 2010) works fine. Just be aware that Qt 4 is only 32 bit, so you need to use the 32 bit versions of OpenNI and NiTE.